# Establishing Happens-Before in Arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, synchronization, happens-before

Have a quick synchronization question, here is what I have:

a) **Class1** has a concurrent hash map defined as follows:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, int[][]> map  = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, int[][]>();
```

b) **Class2** has a thread, called **Thread1**. Thread1 creates an **Id** and checks if **map** contains it. If it does, it retrieves the value (int[][]), modifies the contents and puts it back. If it doesn't, it creates a new int[][] and stores it. This process of check->modify/create happens frequently.

```
 private class Thread1 implements Runnable{

            public void run(){
                //keepRunning is volatile
                while( keepRunning ){

                  String id     = "ItemA";
                  int[][] value = map.get(id);

                  //If value is null, create an int[][] and put it back as value for Id
                  //If value is not null, modify the contents according to some logic  
                 }
             }
    }
```

c) Finally, I have another thread, called **Thread2**. This thread takes an id, checks if the map has a value for it. If it doesn't, nothing happens. If it does, then it sums up the values in int[][] and uses the number for some calculation (no modifications here).

I am trying to figure out if my operations are atomic.
Operations in b) are fine as the creation/modification of the array and insertion into the map is confined to only one thread (**Thread1**).

Also, since insertion into the map establishes a happens-before action, this will ensure that c) will see the updated values in int[][].

However, I am not too sure of what would happen if Thread2 looks up the same int[][] in the map and tries to sum it up while Thread1 is modifying it.

Am I correct in thinking that Thread2 will see the older (but uncorrupted) values in int[][]. Reason being that until Thread1 has finished putting the value back into the map, the new modifications wont be visible to Thread2.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just as side note, you're probably aware if this, but it sounds like your trying to implement a Producer/Consmer pattern, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html for some more ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operations are not atomic, thread 2 will be trying to sum the values while thread 1 is modifying them.

To avoid that you'll need to duplicate the original modify the duplicate and put back the copy.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks. Alternatively, can i not a) Use an AtomicReferenceArray b) Create a new array in b) (instead of getting the old array from the map) and then updating the map with it for a particular Id.